# Need help in "Gradle DSL method not found" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-plugin

I'm rather new to android development. I have been pulling my hair for days and have not been able to figure out how to get it to compile. 
I use

Android Studio 3.1.1
Build #AI-173.4697961, built on April 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Now whenever I try to compile I get this beautiful colorful message that smiles and says:
[image: gradle error]

[image: corresponding Event log]

[image: gradle.build (Module level)]

[image: sample app gradle build]

How can I get to successful compilation? what am I doing wrong here? I'm a newbie so do not assume things. I really don't know how to fix this. tried a few things that are there on the net but none of them works. besides they all are for android studio 2.x something. so maybe those solutions do not apply

Comment: Please post source code (e.g., Gradle files) as text, not images.

Comment: don't want to start a comment war but the main purpose is to show the readers actual error. why does it matter to post the code and not the image. I just want to get my point across clearly which I did.

Comment: "don't want to start a comment war but the main purpose is to show the readers actual error" -- showing the error in a screenshot isn't horrible (though text there too would be useful), and that is not what I commented on. I asked you to post source code as text. "why does it matter to post the code and not the image" -- first, it makes it easier for people like me to copy and paste into answers. Second, it makes it easier for all the developers that follow you to find this material by searching.

Comment: @CommonsWare, believe me you are genius!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second line of your last screenshot is:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30' '1.1.2-5'
```

That is not valid Groovy syntax, and your error is complaining about a `1.2.30()` method invocation, which fits.

Remove one of those two strings. Since `1.2.30` is newer, I suggest trying:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
```

Comment: I'm now getting this error: 12:21 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not find method 1.2.30() for arguments [1.1.2-5] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
     Consult IDE log for more details     12:21 PM Outdated Kotlin Runtime
     Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.10@jar' library is 1.2.10-release-109 (1.2.10), while plugin version is 1.2.31-release-Studio3.1-1.
     Runtime library should be updated to avoid compatibility problems.
     Update Runtime Ignore

Comment: @SimpleFellow: That would suggest that either you didn't make the change, or you have another occurrence of `1.2.30` `1.1.2-5` somewhere.

Comment: it worked, it just did! i see the miracle happening!  .... in the error messages I read update kotlin, so I did. it wanted a restart, I did and it just worked.... so i guess after the removal of false syntax i needed to upgrade

Comment: only if i had posted earlier, i would have saved days and my hair!